# Automatic Save Throughout ASP.NET Application?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, autosave

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ASP.NET Forms autosave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/875834/asp-net-forms-autosave)

I'm looking for general guidance on how to implement an "auto-save" feature in ASP.NET 4.0. I have an application with a tabbed interface (AJAX Control Toolkit) and a user can make changes in a variety of fields and tabs at any given time. I need to create an auto-save for (1) every time changes are made to fields and (2) save everything every 3 seconds (or what not).

I've never implemented something like this and I'm looking for guidance one it. Obviously, I'm assuming that there's some AJAX involved, I just don't know how to go about it.

Comment: **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/875834/asp-net-forms-autosave**

Answer (score 0):

Use a web service with ASP.NET AJAX:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163499.aspx
- http://www.asp.net/ajax/documentation/live/tutorials/ConsumingWebServicesWithAJAXTutorial.aspx
- http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/

You ship off the data to the server using a web service.  You can attach to the change event of the input control (or lostfocus event too), and when it fires, call the web service.  For the every X seconds, use window.setTimeout or window.setInterval, and make the call to send all the pages data to the server.

I don't know if it will perform well by sending data that frequently; are you sure you need to do both?

Answer (score 0):

An easy way would be to

1. Wrap autocomplete form in update panel
2. Attache .change() listeners to all textboxes ect
3. Add a javascript timer to the page
4. In the change event and timer click hidden button to post form back.
5. Maybe have some cute page has been saved text you update during the postback
6. Bam all done